# django contact page sending emails wrongly

Tags: django, django-views

I have made a contact page in my Django project but it sends an email from the email_host_user to itself and does not get the user's email from the contact form, I appreciate your help in advance. I had a setting for email confirmation from the registration page and I am using that same code here.
#settings.py

```
import socket
socket.getaddrinfo('localhost', 25)

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = config("EMAIL_HOST")
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = config("EMAIL_PORT")
EMAIL_HOST_USER = config("EMAIL_HOST_USER")
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = config("EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD")
```

#urls.py

```
from . import views
app_name = 'website'
urlpatterns = [
path('contact', views.contact, name="contact")]
```

#contact.html

```
    <section id="contact" class="contact">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-5 justify-content-center" data-aos="fade-up">
      <div class="col-lg-10">
          {% if name %}
        <h2>Thank you {{ name }}</h2>
         <p>We recieved your email and will respond shortly.</p>
          {% else %}
        <form action="{% url 'website:contact' %}" method="post" role="form" class="php-email-form">
            {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
              <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
              <div class="validate"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
              <div class="validate"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group mt-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject" />
            <div class="validate"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group mt-3">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something for us" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            <div class="validate"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
          </div>
          <div class="text-center"><button type="submit">Send Message</button></div>
        </form>{% endif %}
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</section><!-- End Contact Section -->
```

#views.py

```
def contact(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    name = request.POST['name']
    email = request.POST['email']
    message = request.POST['message']
    subject = request.POST['subject']

    # send email
    send_mail(subject, message, from_email=email, recipient_list=['omranholdinggroup@gmail.com'])
    return render(request, 'website/contact.html')
else:
    return render(request, 'website/contact.html')
```

Comment: And how do you suppose you will send an email from someone else's email id? The email coming from the form likely will not belong to you...

Comment: I tried with my other email :|

Comment: Firstly you are using SMTP, with that you can only send emails from the user you have configured in the settings. Secondly you say you tried with your other email but how would you send an email using that id? You haven't configured it in the settings. Also even if you try with your own email does not mean after you release the website to the public they would be using your email id.

Comment: how should I change it? I'm a novice to python

Comment: What you want to do is not possible (At least legally). Just save the submitted data to the database. You can send an email from the email you configure for SMPT to yourself or other people though. (Just the reverse is not possible as those emails are not yours)

Comment: How may I configure this so that users are able to send message via contact page in my blog?